# Android: unique id for the same user on all devices

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, userid

Is there an unique value to identify the same Android user on different devices?

[ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is a value which identifies the device

but what about a value to identify the user?

if you request the [GET_ACCOUNTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS) permission in your app, you are able to access the email address of the user, but that requires your app to ask the user to grant such permission, which is not very pleasant

Anyone is aware of an unique id that an user keeps on all devices where he uses the same Google account?

Comment: So you want to get the user's account information without asking for permission to get the user's account information?

Comment: @antlersoft, I am not looking for user's account information, but just for a unique id for a user (instead of for a device)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the AccountPicker to get the user account without using additional permission. In this way you have to show to the user a dialog to select the account. Here the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html)